# Virtual Machine: Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am using Virtual Box and I want to run a windows 8.1 on virtual box. My real operating system is windows 8.1 64-bit so I was wondering if I could just copy over the operating system somehow to Virtual Box because I don't like pirating anything. I want to do this to test different programs (possibly malware, I am not sure) on the virtual machine with out harming my real system. I have an Core i5, AMD Radeon Hd 7750, 12 GB DDR3 RAM and a 1 TB hard drive.

Comment: I have a pretty good feeling that by using two copies of your operating system with a single license you are violating terms (i.e. Virtual machines each need a license the same way physical ones do)... There are a few free (and not free) alternatives that might work for you...

Comment: What are the "free (and not free) alternatives" that you speak of?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you are almost surely physically capable of copying over your host operating system to your guest machine, but you are violating law(s) and terms etc.
I have had the same issue regarding wanting to test out programs in isolation with Windows, and here are the alternatives that I can think of that do not seem to violate any laws or terms that I know of.

**Free:**

Use an extra copy of Windows 8 that you have lying around.

Use an evaluation copy of Windows 8 Enterprise that will last you 90 days (if I'm not mistaken). This should be located [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-8-1-enterprise)

Use a DreamSpark Premium subscription (sometimes available if you are CS student at a university) to get a free copy of Windows 8 for personal use.

**Not Free:**

Buy Windows 8.1 (again). This might seem expensive, but there are always discounts.

Use some kind of virtualization solution that offers remote desktop access on a Windows 8 machine. This probably wouldn't be useful for time critical (due to network latency) applications.

In my opinion, if you're going for personal use, the Windows 8 Enterprise trial is probably the easiest way to try out programs, albeit the Windows 8.1 Enterprise is not entirely the same as other Windows 8.1 editions.

Comment: I have a windows 8 recovery disc. Does that count as a extra copy of windows?

Comment: Unless the Windows 8 recovery disk comes with a different computer that is not in use (and won't simultaneously be in use), it does not count as an extra allowable copy of Windows. Unless you are in an enterprise environment (with bulk software licensing for Windows 8), pretty much 1 product key counts for one copy.